# RNN and CNN on activity recognition in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a CNN for activity recognition using 3 sensors. I stacked the dimensions of the sensors giving me 9 channels and divided the time series data into 200 samples per window. I fed it to a 2 CNN layers, 1 fully connected layer and 1 softmax layer. All in Tensorflow

Now I want to replace the fully connected layers with LSTM layers. But I don't know how to implement it. If I have the flattened output from my last convolutional layer how do I feed it into an LSTM layer? How do I apply dropout?

Because I saw a Github code on LSTM fro activity recognition and the input is

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
```

But my flattened output from the last layer is only 2d (-1, N). The n_steps is the number of temporal steps right? Should I reshape my flattened output? How should I reshape it? I believe that `n_steps` in the LSTM code from Github refers to the the number of samples per window. So should I segment the flattened output into 200 samples per window again?

EDIT:
What I want to do is to divide the time series data into slices or time windows, then apply convolutional layers, then flatten this and input it to an LSTM layer. But I don't know how to implement this. Especially when I'm already in the flattened output. How will I segment it and feed it to the recurrent layer?

Answer (score 2):

LSTMs are architecture used with *sequences* of data. Using convolutions on your time dimension makes you losing this time dimension making the use of LSTMs less meaningful.

What I would personally do is replacing the CNN layer with the LSTM one, since both are used to make some aggregation of evidences in the time dimension. In this case I think the answer to your question is clear: `n_steps` are the time steps of your data.

If you still want to apply LSTMs on top of a convolution, then you should design some kind of higher level sequence. One possibility is to provide different windows to the convolutional layer and then use their outputs as input sequence of the LSTM. Obviously this is only a "trick" and you should find good motivations for doing this.

Comment: What I want to do is to divide the time series data into slices or time windows, then apply convolutional layers, then flatten this and input it to an LSTM layer. But I don't know how to implement this. Especially when I'm already in the flattened output. How will I segment it and feed it to the recurrent layer?

Comment: Like if you use LSTM straight, you will apply LSTM to those time windows. However once I apply CNN to the time windows I will flatten it. The problem is, I need to segment this again. Same way as I segmented my original time windows? But the CNN already did maxpooling and other operations so this is an entirely new data.

Comment: As I was trying to say in the answer, you can provide first different windows to the convolutional layer (let's say w0, w1, w2) and then considering their outputs (o0,o1,o2) the inputs of your lstm. Practically you need to use different convolutional net with shared parameters.

Comment: Oh so I wont flatten the output of the convolutional layers? Can you explain further?

Comment: w0 = [t0,t1,t2]; w1 =[t3,t4,t5] w2=[t6,t7,t8]
Then, apply convolutions on the t of each windows.
h0 = convLayer(w0), h1=convLayer(w1), h2=convLayer(w2) (convLayer is the same network, so you must share filters parameters).

Then you have [h0,h1,h2] that is a time series (even though in a different granularity wrt the input) and you can apply it to a LSTM.

Comment: what is w? weight or window?

Comment: Here w are the windows

Comment: is the input to the LSTM a 1D vector?

Comment: Basically, I want to use CNN to capture the local dependencies within the time window while use LSTM to capture the temporal dependencies. How do I go about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147112/discussion-between-giuseppe-marra-and-chaine).